# Model with HttpPostedFileBase property is null on form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, file-upload

I have a model with `HttpPostedFileBase` property that is mapped to a file upload input on my form.  When select a file and submit the form, the model property mapped to the file upload input is null.  How do I resolve this issue?

Model:

```
public class Contact 
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase AttachmentDocument { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "ContactForm", FormMethod.Post, new { @entype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal", @id = "contactform" })) 
{
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">Attached Document:</div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AttachedDocument, new { @type = "file" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Models.Contact model)
{
    //AttachmentDocument is null on submit
}
```

Comment: A little observation that might help, maybe it is a copy-paste error but it is `enctype` not `entype`

Comment: @Bosco - Thanks for finding that!  I have been staring at this code for ages and would have never caught that without a second pair of eyes.

Comment: You're welcome always